# Why are confidence Intervals small when interaction terms are added to a Poisson regression?

Tags: stata, confidence-interval, poisson

I am currently running a Poisson regression with the college applications as the dependent variable, and gender and race as the two independent variables.

I included an full factorial interaction term between gender and race to 1) observe their main effects and 2) observe their interaction effects. Whenever I include their interaction term in the Poisson regression, Stata outputs incidence rate ratios (IRRs) that appear normal, but the corresponding upper and lower limits of the confidence intervals are identical to each other.

I expected that the limits of my 95% confidence intervals (CIs) would **not** be equal to one another **or** their corresponding IRR. When I remove the interaction between the independent variables, the CIs appear as one would generally expect.

```
My code is as follows:

`glm apps i.race##i.gender, family(poisson) link(log) exposure(realpyears) vce(robust) eform`

The output is as follows:


Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -183.25337  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood = -54.374792  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -39.020998  
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -37.736794  
Iteration 4:   log pseudolikelihood = -37.702256  
Iteration 5:   log pseudolikelihood = -37.702146  
Iteration 6:   log pseudolikelihood = -37.702146  

Generalized linear models                         Number of obs   =         12
Optimization     : ML                             Residual df     =         12
                                                  Scale parameter =          1
Deviance         =  5.04042e-14                   (1/df) Deviance =   4.20e-15
Pearson          =  5.19076e-20                   (1/df) Pearson  =   4.33e-21

Variance function: V(u) = u                       [Poisson]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                   [Log]

                                                  AIC             =   6.283691
Log pseudolikelihood =  -37.7021456               BIC             =  -29.81888

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                |               Robust
           apps |        IRR   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           race |
         AI/AN  |   7.571374   3.26e-13  4.7e+13   0.000     7.571374    7.571374
         Asian  |   .9290156   5.49e-16 -1.2e+14   0.000     .9290156    .9290156
         Black  |   1.345809   6.37e-16  6.3e+14   0.000     1.345809    1.345809
      Hispanic  |    1.94419   6.14e-16  2.1e+15   0.000      1.94419     1.94419
         NHoPI  |   1.991199   3.35e-10  4.1e+09   0.000     1.991199    1.991199
                |
         gender |
         Woman  |    .688629   1.66e-16 -1.5e+15   0.000      .688629     .688629
                |
    race#gender |
   AI/AN#Woman  |   1.015982   1.73e-13  9.3e+10   0.000     1.015982    1.015982
   Asian#Woman  |   .9747926   6.28e-16 -4.0e+13   0.000     .9747926    .9747926
   Black#Woman  |    .710833   4.05e-16 -6.0e+14   0.000      .710833     .710833
Hispanic#Woman  |   .6341218   2.43e-16 -1.2e+15   0.000     .6341218    .6341218
   NHoPI#Woman  |   2.381544   4.01e-10  5.2e+09   0.000     2.381544    2.381544
                |
          _cons |    .002722   4.98e-19 -3.2e+16   0.000      .002722     .002722
 ln(realpyears) |          1  (exposure)
```

Comment: Your output indicates you have 12 observations and 12 parameters (since the logarithmic offset is constrained to 1). I am unsure how to reconcile that with your 20K figure in the comment below. Perhaps you have missing data so Stata drops those observations from the model?

Comment: Should've clarified: The above analysis reflects data from a 9-year period in aggregate in which the total events for 2 genders and 6 races were recorded. I realize now that my population size (the number of people at risk per year for 9 years) is not necessarily the problem, perhaps rendering that information less relevant now. But no, there were no missing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is statistical, and nothing to do with your use of Stata or your Stata code. You are throwing a complicated model with several free parameters at a tiny dataset and the fit is almost inevitably excellent. What you see are side-effects of a model that essentially interpolates the data.

Look at your standard errors: they are all of the order of 1 in 10 billion or even **much** less; hence your confidence intervals are just very, very short and the confidence limits are slightly different (but not identical).

The phenomenon is an extension of the fact that two data points in the plane define a straight line uniquely. You need usually many more data points than parameters being estimated. So you need a much larger dataset to assess this model seriously, and the Catch-22 is that omitting the interactions would likely just leave you with a simplistic model.

Comment: Thank you for that clear explanation! Unfortunately, this is as large as my data set can be. The data I am working with is over a 9-year period in a population with ~20,000 individuals at risk per year. Do you have any recommendations for what I should do, especially regarding reporting my confidence intervals in scientific publications?

Comment: Sorry, I have only vacuous suggestions of choosing a different problem.